# Incorporate a while loop in a function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function

Very new to any kind of coding. I would like to write a function that will return the elements of a numeric list, up to the first even number. For example, if the list is [1,5,7,8,9] it will return [1,5,7]

I know the below is not correct, but I am having trouble passing the list into the while loop.

```
def iter_up_to_even(num_lst):
i=0
new_lst=[]
while i < len(num_lst):
    if i%2!=0:
        new_lst.append(num_lst)
        i=i+1
    if i %2==0:
        break 
return new_lst
```

Comment: Access list elements by index with bracket notation: `num_lst[i]`

Comment: Also when asking questions here, please always include the full output (including error messages) from python.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have some indentation issues. Try this solution:

```
def iter_up_to_even(num_list):
    to_return = []
    current_index = 0 if len(num_list) > 0 else len(num_list)
    while current_index < len(num_list):
        if num_list[current_index] % 2 == 1:
            to_return.append(num_list[current_index])
        else:
            break
        current_index += 1
    return to_return
```

**Explanation**

We start with an empty list `to_return`, which we will return at the end of our function. Next, we iterate through each item in the input list `num_list`. If the input list `num_list` is empty to begin with, we don't even enter the while loop *(see Line 3)*. If the item is odd, we append it to our `to_return` list. If it's even, we break from our loop and return `to_return`.

In addition, you should compare values in the list (e.g. `num_list[i]`), rather than the current index in the list (e.g. `i`).

Comment: @user12065217 if you think my answer has solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to it